# Using a collection for sub pages in Jekyll results in Liquid Exception

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

To maintain clarity I like to keep all template files for sub pages in a directory named `_pages`. As Jekyll ignores all directories starting with `_` I need to add the following to my `_config.yml`:

```
include:
  - _pages
```

Even though this already works quite well, a more convenient way to achieve the same results would be to use a [collection](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) for all sub pages. This way the sub pages could be targeted with `type: pages` when defining defaults like shared layouts or meta data.

```
collections:
  pages:
    output: true
```

While the above works like a charm for another project, it throws the following exception when using it for my current project:

```
Liquid Exception: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) in /_layouts/content.html
```

I have no idea how the switch from the include folder method to the collection method could produce this error. Even more odd is that the message does not provide a line number.

The file `content.html` is used as primary layout for the sub pages and got the following content:

```
---
layout: default
---

<div class="o-page o-page--pushed {{ page.style }}">
  {% include navigation.html %}

  <main class="o-page__content{% if page.merge %} u-pv-0x{% endif %}">
    {{ content }}
  </main>

  {% include footer.html %}
</div>
```

**EDIT:** I created a [repository](https://github.com/tnwr/jekyll-pages-collection) which reproduces the issue.

Comment: Do you have a repo which can be cloned to try this?

Comment: @Sirl33tname The actual repo is private, but I was able to reproduce the issue with a minimal version of the site which can be found here: https://github.com/tnwr/jekyll-pages-collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is raised when you call `page.merge`. Because :

- `site.pages` is already a special group of [pages](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pages/), replacing it by a pages collection is not specially a good idea. Once done, you no longer can reach originals pages trough `site.page`, but only new collection's elements.
- When calling `page.merge` on a collection item, Liquid tries to invoke the `Jekyll::Drop::merge` method which needs an argument, and not the `merge` property set in front matter.

Solution : Don't set pages as a collection.

Comment: That’s it! Thank you for pointing me to the `page.merge` variable. I already tried to remove that statement, but then I was confused by another error: `Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error (/_includes/head.html line 7): 'for' tag was never closed included in /_layouts/default.html`. As this error comes from the `jekyll-seo-tag` plugin, I found out that an additional `excerpt_separator: ""` in the config solves it. Do you know how this is related to the switch from the include folder method to the collection method?